# alertmanager: custom receiver or webhook receiver with custom POST payload?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

Is there a way to modify the webhook receiver's POST payload?

If not: is there documentation or a template on how to write an own receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was looking for the same thing, and ended-up finding couple of issues on alertmanager repository informing that webhook receiver currently does not support this type of customization.

Seems the general consensus is that when using a webhook receiver one should write its own application to send notifications to the provider of choice.

- [Prometheus/Alertmanager: Issue 1422](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/pull/1422)
- [Prometheus/Alertmanager: Issue 1496](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/1496)